# Entity framework codefirst,how to prevent add foreignkey in mysql

Tags: mysql, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I don't want to add foreignkeys in database,but entities relation still exists.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use foreign keys?

Comment: @Stefan     I don't want to detele related data ,but foreignKeys asked me to hava to delete.

Comment: Set CascadeDelete to false at generated migration.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov That still adds foreignkeys in database , and I have to delete relational data at first , then delete primary table data.

Comment: One way is to use `[NotMapped]` on your navigation properties. You'll then have to `join` them manually.

Comment: Oh , I have to delete foreignkeys in database , thank you.@Stefan